# Number of Row with If Statement

Tags: ios, swift

I have a table view populated with data from a JSON. So far so good! But i want my table view (Number of rows) to be populated only if an id in the json is equal to something specific. In my case:
"ttc_proposta_tipo_id" = "e0eb2736-433e-475e-876d-bcc6b460e1e3"

if not, return 0

I dont know if i was clear enough, this is my first question.

Thanx

My code:

```
class NavigationTest: UIViewController{

@IBOutlet weak var btnAddProposta: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

var propostas = [Proposta]()

private var refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupSideMenu()
    fetchJSON()
    self.tableView.register(CustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

}

struct Proposta: Decodable {
    let TtcProposta: TtcProposta
    let TtcBasaFinalidade: TtcBasaFinalidade
    let TtcCar: [TtcCar]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case TtcProposta = "TtcProposta"
        case TtcBasaFinalidade = "TtcBasaFinalidade"
        case TtcCar = "TtcCar"
    }
}

struct TtcProposta: Decodable {
    let id: String?
    let user_id: Int?
    let versao: String?
    let status_processo: String?
    let finalidade: String?
    let valor_proposta: String?
    let detalhes_json: detalhes_json?
    let ativo: Bool?
    let modified: String?
    let inst_financeira_id: String?
    let ttc_basa_finalidade_id: String?
    let seq: Int?
    let ttc_proposta_tipo_id: String?
    let data_envio: String?
    let liberado_banco: String?
    let numero_fip: String?
    let numeroProtocolo: String?
    let created: String?
}

fileprivate func fetchJSON() {
    let urlPath = "http://credito-homologacao.branch.terras.agr.br/ttc/ttc_propostas/get_by_user"
    let url = NSURL(string: urlPath)
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "GET" // make it post if you want
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in


        guard let data = data else { return }

        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            // Swift 4.1
            decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
            self.propostas = try decoder.decode([Proposta].self, from: data)


            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        } catch let jsonErr {
            print("Error serializing json:", jsonErr)
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

extension:

```
extension NavigationTest: UITableViewDataSource {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //THIS IS WHAT TRIED AND IT DIDNT WORK
    //ERROR:Value of type '[NavigationTest.Proposta]' has no member 'TtcProposta'

    if propostas.TtcProposta.ttc_proposta_tipo_id == "e0eb2736-433e-475e-876d-bcc6b460e1e3" {
        return propostas.count
    }
    return 0

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell") as! CustomCell
    let proposta = propostas[indexPath.row]

    cell.delegate = self

    cell.numeroProposta.text = proposta.TtcProposta.numeroProtocolo
    cell.proponenteNome.text = proposta.TtcProposta.finalidade

    return cell
}
```

Comment: you got the error because the `propostas` is array type. It does not have `TtcProposta`.

Comment: do you want to check if the specific string is equal to any of the `proposta` or every `proposta`?

Comment: Do yourself a favour and decide on _one_ strategy to convert your keys. Currently your `CodingKeys` are just a noop and you somewhat switch your strategy half way through since the `TtcProposta` struct uses a strategy different from the `Proposta` struct (where your `CodingKeys` enum could just as well be omitted). I am astonished `.convertFromSnakeCase` does not flat out refuse to decode your JSON, but obviously miracles will never cease. It is always sound advice to apply great care to your model objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do that in `numberOfRowsInSection`, it's the wrong place, check right after having decoded the JSON.

Create an array of all `id` values and check if it contains the given `id`.
If the check succeeds assign the `result` otherwise assign an empty array.

```
let result = try decoder.decode([Proposta].self, from: data)
let ids = result.compactMap { $0.TtcProposta.id }
if ids.contains("e0eb2736-433e-475e-876d-bcc6b460e1e3") {
    self.propostas = result 
} else {
    self.propostas = []
}
```

Edit: If you want to filter all elements with given `id` write

```
let result = try decoder.decode([Proposta].self, from: data)
self.propostas = result.filter { $0.TtcProposta.id == "e0eb2736-433e-475e-876d-bcc6b460e1e3" }
```

and return in `numberOfRowsInSection` as usual

```
return propostas.count
```

Side note: Why do you set the option `.convertFromSnakeCase` but you don't use *camelCased* property names?

Comment: its still not filtering... I'm still getting all the elements from the json.

Comment: The code returns all records if the `id` of one of them is equal to the reference `id` or nothing according to your request in the question.

Comment: I would like to populate my table view with only the elements in which "ttc_proposta_tipo_id" is equal to "e0eb2736-433e-475e-876d-bcc6b460e1e3"... im sorry for not so clear

Answer (score 0):

Using filter would be the simplest.

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
// Swift 4.1
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
self.propostas = try decoder.decode([Proposta].self, from: data).filter { return $0.ttc_proposta_tipo_id == "e0eb2736-433e-475e-876d-bcc6b460e1e3" }
```